# CatBoostRegression predict on test straight line

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, catboost

CatBoostRegressor in test dataset fits a straight line

[image: Red is CatBoostRegressor]

The first graph is train dataset ( CatBoostRegressor trained based on noised sin )
The second graph is test data set

Why does it fit a straight line? The same for other functions ( as f(x)=x etc )

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = func(x) + np.random.normal(0, 3, len(x))

x_test = np.linspace(0*np.pi, 4*np.pi, 200)
y_test = func(x_test)

train_pool = Pool(x.reshape((-1,1)), y)
test_pool = Pool(x_test.reshape((-1,1))) 

model = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=100, depth=2, loss_function="RMSE",
                          verbose=True
                          )
model.fit(train_pool)

y_pred = model.predict(x.reshape((-1,1)))
y_test_pred = model.predict(test_pool)

poly = Polynomial(4)
p = poly.fit(x,y);


plt.plot(x, y, 'ko')
plt.plot(x, func(x), 'k')
plt.plot(x, y_pred, 'r')
plt.plot(x, poly.evaluate(p, x), 'b')

plt.show()

plt.plot(x_test, y_test, 'k')
plt.plot(x_test, y_test_pred, 'r')
plt.show()
plt.plot(x_test, y_test, 'k')
plt.plot(x_test, poly.evaluate(p, x_test), 'b')
plt.show()
```

Comment: because your hyper-parameters are not chosen properly

Answer (score 0):

This is because **decision trees are piecewise constant functions**, and Catboost fully is based on decision trees. So *catboost always extrapolates wiht a constant*.

Therefore, Catboost (and other tree-based algorithms, like XGBoost, or all implementations of Random Forest) is poor at extrapolation (unless you do a clever feature engineering, which in fact extrapolates by itself).

In your example, Catboost extrapolates sine with a constant, which is uncool. But polynomial fit is even worse: it quickly goes to infinity!

[image]

This is the full code that generates the picture:

```
import numpy as np
func = np.sin
from catboost import Pool, CatBoostRegressor
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import Polynomial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1)

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = func(x) + np.random.normal(0, 3, len(x))

x_test = np.linspace(0*np.pi, 4*np.pi, 200)
y_test = func(x_test)

train_pool = Pool(x.reshape((-1,1)), y)
test_pool = Pool(x_test.reshape((-1,1))) 

model = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=100, depth=2, loss_function="RMSE",verbose=False)
model.fit(train_pool, verbose=False)

y_pred = model.predict(x.reshape((-1,1)))
y_test_pred = model.predict(test_pool)

p = np.polyfit(x, y, deg=4)

plt.scatter(x, y, s=3, c='k')
plt.plot(x_test, y_test, 'k')
plt.plot(x_test, y_test_pred, 'r')
plt.plot(x_test, np.polyval(p, x_test), 'b')
plt.title('Out-of-sample performance of trees and polynomials')
plt.legend(['training data', 'true', 'catboost', 'polynomial'])
plt.ylim([-4, 4])
plt.show()
```